# Python 3.10 read from playlist file, wrong first character of first line

Tags: python, io

**File: main_nested.aimppl**

```
#Name:Διάφορα εκκλησιαστικά
#Cursor:-1
#Flags:2047
#Group:/home/chris/Documents/papinhio-player/src/python+/menu-1/playlists/test-playlists/mp3/|1
#Track:1|/home/chris/Documents/papinhio-player/src/python+/menu-1/playlists/test-playlists/mp3/ΥΜΝΟΙ/ΑΓΙΟΙ ΑΓΓΕΛΟΙ.mp3||||ΑΓΙΟΙ ΑΓΓΕΛΟΙ|0|0|||0|0|0|
#Track:1|/home/chris/Documents/papinhio-player/src/python+/menu-1/playlists/test-playlists/mp3/ΥΜΝΟΙ/Αγνή Παρθένε Δέσποινα.mp3||||Αγνή Παρθένε Δέσποινα|0|0|||0|0|0|
#Track:1|/home/chris/Documents/papinhio-player/src/python+/menu-1/playlists/test-playlists/.aimppl/nested/ΑΝΑΣΤΑΣΙΜΑ.aimppl||||ΑΝΑΣΤΑΣΙΜΑ|0|0|||0|0|0|
#Track:1|/home/chris/Documents/papinhio-player/src/python+/menu-1/playlists/test-playlists/.aimppl/nested/ΥΜΝΟΙ.aimppl||||ΥΜΝΟΙ|0|0|||0|0|0|
```

**File: read_playlist_file.py**

```py
import os
import sys

with open("main_nested.aimppl") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line[0])
```

Output:

```
chris@chris-Inspiron-3847:~/Desktop$ python3 read_playlist_file.py 

#
#
#
#
#
#
#
```

Expected output:

```
chris@chris-Inspiron-3847:~/Desktop$ python3 read_playlist_file.py 
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
```

As you can see in the first line there is no # print.

This file was created from python3.10.
Maybe you can't reproduce this problem.
Maybe it's a utf-bom character issue.

This code works:

```py
import io

f = io.open('main_nested.aimppl', 'rt', encoding='utf_8_sig')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line[0])
```

What's the problem with the first code, and what it's the appropriate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Maybe it's a utf-bom character issue." Yes, that's it. You can check your file with e.g. `hexdump -c` on the command line. The first 3 bytes should be 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF if it's a utf8-with-BOM file.

"what it's the appropriate solution?" What you did is exactly right. `encoding='utf_8_sig'` is for utf8-with-BOM files.